# Converting an Enumeration to Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, nullpointerexception, enumeration

I have a problem on a worksheet which is to create an adapter to convert an Enumeration to an Iterator. When I try to run the following code I get a null pointer exception.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ConvertEnumeration {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int [] ourArray = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        Vector vector = new Vector(Arrays.asList(ourArray));

        //Get Enumerator 
        Enumeration enumerator = vector.elements();

        EnumerationToIterator enumToIt = new EnumerationToIterator(enumerator);
        while(enumToIt.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(enumToIt.next());
        }
    }

}


//Convert our enumeration to Iterator!
class EnumerationToIterator implements Iterator {

    //Our enumeration
    Enumeration enmueration;

    //Constructor
    public EnumerationToIterator(Enumeration enmueration){
        enmueration = this.enmueration;
    }

    //Our Methods
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return enmueration.hasMoreElements();
    }

    public Object next(){
        return enmueration.nextElement();
    }

    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Another point to note is that I can not print out the int's from the Enumeration after I have created it in the first place.

Comment: Any chance that you'll consider switching the accepted answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073094/converting-an-enumeration-to-iterator/20696950#20696950)? It has nearly 10 times more upvotes than the accepted answer, and this question is one of the top search results for `java enumeration to iterator`, so it might be nice to have the main answer be the one more generalizable to most developers' needs.

Comment: The point of the original question was _how_ to do it myself.. 

I understand the other answer has more upvotes but it didn't solve the question I was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class ConvertEnumeration {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // int [] ourArray = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));

        //Get Enumerator 
        Enumeration<Integer> enumerator = vector.elements();

        EnumerationToIterator<Integer> enumToIt = new EnumerationToIterator<Integer>(enumerator);
        while(enumToIt.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(enumToIt.next());
        }
    }

}    

//Convert our enumeration to Iterator!
    class EnumerationToIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        //Our enumeration
        Enumeration<T> enmueration;

        //Constructor
        public EnumerationToIterator(Enumeration<T> enmueration){
            this.enmueration = enmueration;
        }

        //Our Methods
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return enmueration.hasMoreElements();
        }

        public T next(){
            return enmueration.nextElement();
        }

        public void remove(){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding generic type in your main class help? See my updated answer.

Comment: Tried mate still no luck, the line, "Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ourArray));" Gives the error, "The constructor Vector<Integer>(List<int[]>) is undefined"

Answer (score 56):

### Java 5 and Later

No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use `Collections.list(Enumeration<T> e)`, which returns an `ArrayList<T>`. Then use `ArrayList.iterator()` to get an `Iterator`.

### Java 9 and Later

Enumerations now [have a method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Enumeration.html#asIterator()) to convert directly to an iterator:

```
enumeration.asIterator();
```

Comment: An adapter is a better choice because the number of elements could be huge and an `ArrayList` with all the elements increases the memory consumption.

Comment: @ChristianUllenboom I wouldn't call it better just because there are situations in which it's better. This answer is excellent for most uses.

Answer (score 9):

Java 9 offers a new default method: `Iterator<E> asIterator()`

Answer (score 7):

Wrong assignment in your constructor. It needs to be `this.enmueration = enmueration;`
`enmueration` is the constructor argument, and `this.enmueration` is the object attribute.

Comment: Ah school boy error, thanks!! Quick question, that got rid of the error but when I try to print out the original values, it only prints a memory address (I think), e.g "[I@38f0b51d" . Trying to cast to an int gives this error, "I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"

Comment: What is inside your `System.out.println();` ?

Comment: System.out.println(enumToIt.next()); gives the garbage and System.out.println((int)enumToIt.next()) gives an error

Comment: I updated the original code - it may not be visible, yet. Let me know if it solved the problem.

Comment: @jlordo: FYI, your edit was rejected as it changed the code of the original post. Instead of editing the original (buggy) code, you should edit your answer to include suitably amended code.

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks for letting me know. It was the easiest way continuing to help the OP after answering the original question.

Comment: Yes, I understand the motivation. Unfortunately, editing the original code to fix bugs also risks invalidating the question itself. Therefore, the recommended approach is to copy and amend the relevant parts into your own post. HTH, and thanks for your answers!